# SQL doesn't return correct values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So, I have a simple SQL query, which however seems to be bugged (or my `where-clause` is written wrong), as it doesn't return a value if I select on a specific field (`matflag`) with a specific value (`50`).

The query is basically a `select from table1` with a subquery on `table2` where the `where-clause` just checks if the returned field from the subquery exists in `table1`:

```
Select distinct  
    t1.matnum as matnum, t1.matflag as matflag, t1.factory as factory 
from 
    table1 t1, 
    (select matnum from table2 where technical_value = 'XX') t2 
where 
    t1.matnum = t2.matnum and t1.matnum = '60000000';
```

This returns this output:

```
+----------+---------+---------+
| MATNUM   | MATFLAG | FACTORY |
+----------+---------+---------+
| 60000000 |         | 001000  |
| 60000000 |         | 002000  |
| 60000000 |         | 003000  |
| 60000000 |         | 004000  |
| 60000000 |         | 005000  |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

If I, however add `and t1.matflag != '50'` to the end of the `where-clause`, the whole output disappears.

```
Select distinct 
    t1.matnum as matnum, t1.matflag as matflag, t1.factory as factory 
from 
    table1 t1, 
    (select matnum from table2 where technical_value = 'XX') t2 
where 
    t1.matnum = t2.matnum 
    and t1.matnum = '60000000' 
    and t1.matflag != '50';
```

Output:

```
+----------+---------+---------+
| MATNUM   | MATFLAG | FACTORY |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

Additional information for the column `matflag`: It is a varchar2(2 Char) column, either filled with nothing or the value '50' or the value '10' or '20'.
Now, if I change the where clause from `and t1.matflag != '50'` to `and t1.matflag is null`, the output is correct again:

```
Select distinct 
    t1.matnum as matnum, t1.matflag as matflag, t1.factory as factory 
from 
    table1 t1, 
    (select matnum from table2 where technical_value = 'XX') t2 
where 
    t1.matnum = t2.matnum 
    and t1.matnum = '60000000' 
    and t1.matflag is null;
```

So this returns this output:

```
+----------+---------+---------+
| MATNUM   | MATFLAG | FACTORY |
+----------+---------+---------+
| 60000000 |         | 001000  |
+----------+---------+---------+
.... and so on, have a look at the first table above
```

So how does it return something if I select on `is null` but not if I select on `!= '50'`? (Sidenote: changing `!=` to `<>` didn't help either)

How does `matflag is null` apply but `matflag != '50'` not?

We run the Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production.

Comment: In SQL `NULL` means "unknown" value, thus and operation with it will result in `NULL`, that is `BOOLEAN`ized as `FALSE`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn how to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
Select distinct t1.matnum as matnum, t1.matflag as matflag, t1.factory as factory 
from table1 t1 join
     table2
     on t1.matnum = t2.matnum
where t2.technical_value = 'XX' and t1.matnum = '60000000';
```

Then learn about `NULL` values and how they fail almost every comparison, including `<>`.

The logic you want is:

```
where t2.technical_value = 'XX' and t1.matnum = '60000000' and
      (matflag <> '50' or matflag is null)
```

Comment: Hello Gordon,
I probably should have added that to the question that I got it working with a simple join already - I was just interested about the other things, which helped me quite a lot, thanks! I'll have a deeper look at `NULL`-values, just didn't thought I would need that until now.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL `NULL` means "unknown" value, thus any operation with it will result in `NULL`. Try `COALESCE(t1.matflag, 0) <> 50`...

Comment: Thank you, interesting attempt! I'll however stick to Gordons attempt I think, now that I know why my comparison fails. Upvoted tho!